# Join values of two string lists to new string list and add characters in VB.NET using LINQ

Tags: list, vb.net, linq

In VB.NET i would like to create a list of string from the values of two given lists of string.

E.g.

```vb
        Dim varNames As New List(Of String)({"var1", "var2"})
        Dim varValues As New List(Of String)({"value1", "value2"})
        Dim finalList As List(Of String) = .....
        'Output should be:
        'finalList(0) -> "[var1] = 'value1'"
        'finalList(1) -> "[var2] = 'value2'"
```

I would like to do this in on line of code using LINQ. (I know how to do this using for loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0) to "concat" two lists via index:

```
Dim finalList As List(Of String) = varNames.
    Zip(varValues, Function(s1, s2) $"[{s1}] = '{s2}'").
    ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not give the result i need. Concat produces one list with all elemts of the given lists.

  (0): "var1"
    (1): "var2"
    (2): "value1"
    (3): "value2"

But i would like to add characters and join the elements from the given lists.

(0): "[var1] = 'value1'"
(1): "[var2] = 'value2'"

Comment: @gegy: ok, i got it, edited the answer.. use Zip

Comment: YES! Thats it! Thank you so much! :)